# Network request before ListView reaches the end. Lazy loading

Tags: flutter, dart, lazy-loading

To add additional data to the `ListView` I use `maxScrollExtent`

```
  _controller.addListener(() {
    if (_controller.position.pixels == _controller.position.maxScrollExtent){
       //Get data request here
   });
```

But I wanted the user to not wait for the data to load, and load the data a little earlier, at 70% -80% of the list length. I tried such a solution but it does not work `_controller.position.maxScrollExtent-200`

Nothing happens, there is no error, the `_controller.addListener` is not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please change condition from `==` to `>=` 
I have tested with your previous question 
code snippet

```
_controller.addListener(() {
    if (_controller.position.pixels == _controller.position.maxScrollExtent - 200){
       //Get data request here
   });
```

to

```
_controller.addListener(() {
    if (_controller.position.pixels >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent - 200){
       //Get data request here
   });
```

Comment: Thank you, I found my mistake. Your code is working. But the problem is that the Listiner is triggered many times and I will look for another way.